# Javascript Regex url replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use a regex to replace image,video and other urls that come overs as messages. I thought everything was working but I am running into a problem with the last case of replacing urls like www.google.com. It is now adding localhost:3000 to the front of those url. I am not the best with regex but it looks like the regex is working in the HTML as the href is www.google.com. Can anyone help see where this is going wrong?

```
var image_url = /([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))/i;
var message = text.replace(image_url,'<a href="$1" target="_blank"><img    width=100px height=100px src="$1"/></a>')
var video_url = /([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(mp4|webm|ogg))/i;
message = message.replace(video_url,'<a href="$1" target="_blank"><video src="$1"></video></a>')
var exp_url = /(?:^|[^"'])(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi;
message = message.replace(exp_url,'<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>')
```

Comment: Not entirely understanding the problem... can you post a bit more of the code? Particularly what is the value of the 'text' variable?

Comment: text is a message sent by a user so it can be anything. The job of this function is to check if it is an image,video or url and replace it with the correct tag. The first two seem to be working correctly but the last one wants to add localhost:3000 to the front of it

Comment: If the problem is only with the last one, can you reduce the question to that only? It seems unnecessary we look at the part of the code that is working.

Comment: Do *you* want to add the `localhost:3000`? Or are you saying that magically there is an unwanted `localhost:3000` appearing somewhere? Please provide the `message` value we can reproduce the problem with.

Comment: I added that because the final regex(exp_url) has to account for them adding in an anchor tag and ignore the url if it finds an anchor tag already

Comment: It magically adds in. It could be because it doesn't have http:// on the front. But a message would just be "www.google.com" and clicking it would bring you to http://localhost:3000/www.google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to figure it out. I wasn't adding http:// if it wasn't there.

```
var image_url = /([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))/i;
var message = text.replace(image_url,'<a href="$1" target="_blank"><img width=100px height=100px src="$1"/></a>')
var video_url = /([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(mp4|webm|ogg))/i;
message = message.replace(video_url,'<a href="$1" target="_blank"><video src="$1"></video></a>')
var http_reg = /(?:^|[^"'])(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
message = message.replace(http_reg, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
var www_reg = /(?:^|[^"'])(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
message = message.replace(www_reg, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
```