# Regex to replace number in url

Tags: javascript

Similar to many questions such as [Javascript Regex url replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900302/javascript-regex-url-replace)

But I'm trying to replace a number in a URL string i.e.

```
filename.replace('org\/*\/','org/23/')
```

The URL is much longer, but I just need to replace the number that comes after `org/`

ie. `assets/org/1/course/154/805597a6-9c35-4f13-af83-ebfdcb12f769/upload_87bf778b-44ee-4a39-8765-ee9c4b9f3126.jpg`

Comment: `\/org\/([\d]+)`

Comment: hmm thanks. Not working, not sure why. Looks like it should do.

Comment: The first argument is passed a string and matches nothing. Even if it was passed as a regex the `*` would apply to `/` and be "match none or many `/`". What you want would look like `filename.replace(/org\/\d+\//, 'org/23/')`

Comment: cheers bro can you put it as an answer and I'll mark it correct

Comment: No need. Accept Aziz answer when he fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current regex you're passing is being interpreted as a string. You need to use the forward-slashes or `RegExp` class to indicate you're passing a regex

```js
let filename = "assets/org/1/course/154/805597a6-9c35-4f13-af83-ebfdcb12f769/upload_87bf778b-44ee-4a39-8765-ee9c4b9f3126.jpg"
console.log(filename.replace(/org\/([0-9]+)\//,'org/23/'))
```

Comment: Two comments. 1) `[0-9]+` can be reduced to `\d+` and 2) there is no need to capture the numbers if you're not going to use them.